# Trouble accessing webservice from EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, bottle

I have a small bottle webservice running on EC2 virtual windows server i launched. I am able to access it on localhost or by using the IPV4 specified in the main method as below but I am not able to access it over internet from other computers. 
Please suggest me how to deal with this. I saw one similar question like this but the suggestions didnt work so am posting again. Apologies for that.
Trying:`http://172.31.30.244:8080/`

```
@route('/')
def index():
    """ Display welcome & instruction messages """
    return "<p>Welcome to bottle powered server !</p> \
           <p>There are many ways to invoke the web service :\
       <ul><li>http://localhost:8080/in?s=type_your_string_here</li>\
       </ul>"
```

### some code here for calculations

## IN my Main method

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bottle.debug(True)
    run(host='172.31.30.244', port=8080,debug=True)
```

Comment: do you have a security group attached to the EC2 instance with the port 8080 open?

Comment: my security group is configured like below:
Inbount
TYPE     Protocol      PORT RANGE        SOURCE
RDP    TCP  3389  0.0.0.0/0
Custome TCP RULE TCP  8080  0.0.0.0/0
HTTP   TCP  80  0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS   TCP  443  0.0.0.0/0

Outbound
TYPE     Protocol      PORT RANGE     SOURCE
All traffic  All  All   0.0.0.0/0

Comment: can you try putting `run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)` in the last line of your main method?

Comment: I just tried that but the service is not accessible through http://0.0.0.0:8080 although in the terminal it shows running also it is inaccessible over network from remote browser.
should i change any settings in security group?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that ip 174.31.30.244 is not the instance ip, the 0.0.0.0 parameter tells the app to run on whatever attached ip the box is. You can find the ip on the instance details page, it usually starts with aws-compute

Comment: Pardon me, it's the public dns you're looking for.

Comment: Public DNS: ec2-54-169-10-124.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Instance ID
i-3ab14411
Public DNS
ec2-54-169-10-124.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Instance state
running
Public IP
54.169.10.124
Instance type
t2.small
Elastic IP
-
Private DNS
ip-172-31-30-244.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
Availability zone
ap-southeast-1a

Comment: should i use this in my code somewhere. I tried it in browser but I am getting access denied

Comment: Is the run function call still with the 0.0.0.0 host param?

Comment: if __name__ == '__main__':
 bottle.debug(True)
 run(host='172.31.30.244', port=8080,debug=True)

Comment: Change that ip to 0.0.0.0 instead of 174..., you're binding it to your local ip not to the public one.

Comment: sorry i changed it to 0.0.0.0 but as i stated earlier it is inaccessible even to local browser

Comment: If you don't mind having a look, i can share my instance login details with you over email. :)

Comment: I don't have a computer at hand, sorry.

Comment: no probs. i changed to 0.0.0.0 but access isnt there..

Comment: Any success on this?

Comment: yes i managed to do this. Ran bottle server on EC2 instance, opened a port 8083 and accessed using the fully_qualified_machine_name:8083
thank you for your suggestion on using the public DNS name. I was not opening the port properly which i later did using custom TCP under 'Add rule' for inbounds of EC2 instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran bottle server on EC2 instance, opened a port 8083 and accessed using the fully_qualified_machine_name:8083 thank you for your suggestion on using the public DNS name. I was not opening the port properly which i later did using custom TCP under 'Add rule' for inbounds of EC2 instance